# Bootstrap - visible-xs- usage

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, fluid-layout

Can we use visible-xs and other classes to have multiple containers?
My requirement is to use the following:

Use container-fluid(968px width) for Desktop and use container for tablets(take fixed full-width). How can I achieve it? Is it possible with the classes

visible-xs-container 
Is it a good practice?

Should I write media query or override css?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine bootstrap classes for single div:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-xs-1">
```

Comment: Can I use class container-fluid for Desktop and use class container for tablets  in a single html page?

Comment: @Smitha yes you can. But depends on what you want. Maybe there is better way?

Comment: i have been told to utilize full width for tablet and keep fluid layout for desktop. So wanted to know can i achieve it using visible- classes or are media query better way?

Comment: @Smitha You can achieve that using `visible-` and `hidden-` as they already are written using media queries

Comment: Okay..can you just give me the exampel of how to achieve it? I am bit confused. Is it a good practice